# Symfony2 composite key constraint in Form builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

What would be the best place to insert composite key validation constraint into a Form builder, that is tied to `FOSUserBundle`'s `User` entity?

Let me elaborate.

I have a `User` entity which extends `FOSUserBundle\Model\User`. I added several fields (`team` field, specifically). Each `User` belongs to exactly one `Team`.

Now, I want to make a registration system that allows user to become a member of one specific team, directly (by having a route such as `/register/{teamSlug}`). New user has to enter his email address, but email must be unique only on a team level. This constraint translates to `UNIQUE KEY team_email (team_id, email)` in database of choice.

Naturally, I will have an unique key defined in database table, but that would only make sure that no data gets inserted, while throwing a database exception when invalid write is attempted.

I considered using `@UniqueEntity` attribute on `User` entity, but it doesn't seem to work:

(Edit: I added a missing `use` statement.)

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"email", "team"},
 *     message="This email already exists in this team."
 * )
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    // ...
}
```

The other thing that I found is [the callback assert](http://symfony.com/doc/2.6/reference/constraints/Callback.html). Maybe I could use it to verify if email exists in the team scope when validation of FormBuilder instance with data_class of `MyBundle\Entity\User` runs, however, that will break encapsulation of Entity since it requires Entity to know about its own Repository, and so on.

What is the best approach to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

unique entity works fine but you need to define the right validation groups to make it working with fos user

> ```
> @UniqueEntity(
>        fields={"email", "team"},
>        groups={"Registration", "Profile"},
>        message="This email already exists in this team."
>   )
> ```

Comment: I wasn't very clear - I have added the `use` statement (without it, I kept receiving a very descriptive exception). I have edited my question to reflect that. But, I didn't know that `groups` apply to `@UniqueEntity`, too.

Comment: Unfortunately - no. I have added UniqueEntity as you said, added correct groups, configured Form to use right validation group. When I populate email field and validate form, it executes zero queries against database (I have enabled mysql query logging just for this purpose).

Comment: Perhaps `@UniqueEntity` is triggered only before persisting entity to the database?